# Electrical Machine Design: Why do open slots are allowed in synchronous machine while they are avoided in Inductio Machine

Tags: induction-motor, electrical, synchronous-motor

Why do open slots are allowed in stator and rotor of synchronous machine while they are avoided in stator of Induction Machine?

Because flux from stator to rotor (IM)  and from rotor to stator (in SM Cylindrical rotor), will have nearly same linkage.

I know large air gap between stator and rotor of synchronous machine make it less noisy. But what effect the shape of stator slots have on machine's performance.

Comment: You are going to have to clarify what you are asking.  What slots?  The stator can be identical.  Rotor can have a SCIM built in (for starting), but slots are needed to magnetize rotor.

Comment: I have now clarified. When comparing IM and SM I was talking of stator slots.